# Cannot disable fan on Dell Optiplex 7070

Tags: dell, fan

I am trying to completely disable the fan of my Optiplex 7070 running Ubuntu 20.04.1.

After installing i8kutils and modprobing i8k (with force=1 for modprobe to be successful), I can now control the fan speed with i8kctl (basically: full speed, normal speed, low speed).

However, disabling the fans entirely does not actually disable them: "i8kctl fan 0 0" makes the (unique) fan run at 736 rpm (according to lm-sensors), not 0 rpm.  It never goes below this, even for just one second, even though all the core temperatures are around 23 degrees C.

How can I disable the fan entirely?

I have also tried smm (bundled with i8kctl), with the same effect, as well as dell-fan-mon, which complains that it cannot detect cpu temp sensor id but then apparently it is meant to work with laptops anyway and Optiplex 7070 is not one.

I also note that I have disabled the fan control override option in the BIOS.

Comment: Have you run `sensors-detect` since this is a desktop?  If there are any super-io chips detected then you can do this with pwm.  Are you looking to turn it on and off when you want or keep it off all the time?

Comment: Yes I have run sensors-detect, it detects one fan (dell_smm-virtual-0), nothing which looks like a super-io chip. The speed of this fan can also be accessed through /sys/devices/virtual/hwmon/hwmon3/fan1_input and this directory contains a pwm1 file but no pwm1_enable file. Writing to pwm1 has no effect. As a first step I am looking to turn it off all the time, even just turning it off for 3 seconds would be a progress.